# What are the disadvantages of the new Viltrox 85mm f/1.8 versus Sony's current 85mm offerings?

Tags: lens, sony, 85mm, e-mount

The Viltrox 85mm f/1.8 is a relatively new lens and there don't seem to be any comparisons between it and the 85mm lineup that Sony currently offers. I get that's it's a manual focus lens, but I am interested to see how it stacks up optically against something like the entry level FE 85mm f/1.8. Anyone had any hands on experience with this lens and any of Sony's to draw am optical comparison?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just spent a few weeks with the [viltrox 85mm f/1.8](https://ayrne.io/photography/cameras/lenses/viltrox-85mm-f1-8-sony/) for a review project I've been working on and I've shot the Sony FE 85mm f/1.8 in the past. It's not quite as perceptually sharp or punchy as the Sony and the colors aren't as vibrant. Chromatic aberration is definitely a lot more noticeable on this lens than the Sony and of course, it's heavier and manual focus. I'd say it has more of a classic or vintage lens optical quality going for it. I haven't had the opportunity to shoot the Sony GM or Zeiss 85mm f/1.8 lenses, but, it seems reasonable to assume that those would be optically better than Sony's entry level 85mm, therefore, significantly better than the Viltrox. The Viltrox is almost half the price though, so if you're ok getting a little less overall optical quality and using manual focus, this might be a worthwhile venture.